# The meaning of “for the first time”

Tags: meaning

Why does “for the first time” only mean in a certain way?

For example, he drove the car for the first time.

Can it mean he drove the car for the first time of times **people** drove the car? I mean, he’s the first person who drove the car.

Why do people only use “for the first time” to mean that he drove the car for the first time of times **he** drove the car?

Comment: They don't mean the same thing. The first is not grammatical anyway. It should read *It's the first time he **has** used the fire.* It implies that he is currently using the fire and it is the first time he has done so. The second sentence indicates that his use of the fire has ended, though when he did so it was the first time.

Comment: It sounds odd to speak of _using a fire_. Do you mean that he _used fire_ (the physical process of burning), or that he used _a fire_ (a particular heap of burning fuel)? We would normally say _He warmed himself at the fire_ or _He cooked (something) on the fire_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I actually wrote anything to know what “for the first time” is.

Comment: Oh, so you wrote these sentences yourself? Then I agree with WS2. _It's the first time he **has** driven the car_ (he is driving it now and has never done so before). _He drove the car for the first time (yesterday)_.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is it about differentiating the various meanings of the word "time"? In "for the first time" the word "time" has a different meaning from the one it has in "at the beginning of the time". If you do not see that difference,  you should first consult a dictionary and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @Kate Bunting But the literal meaning of “for the first time” is ‘at the beginning of the time.’ Why does it mean ‘for the first time of times he drove the car’?

Comment: @None But I think it’s too late to modify the question.

Comment: You click on "edit" and you can modify as long and as many **times** as you like. (Same meaning of "time" in my sentence as in both your examples).

Comment: You've tried but it's still not very clear. Have you really compared all the various meanings of "time" and "times"  in a dictionary? "For the fist time" doesn't mean "for the first time of times" (I have difficulty understanding what you mean by that last phrase, I expect there in an interference with something you say in your mother tongue but I can't see what)

Comment: @None https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=time&submit.x=0&submit.y=0 It seems that we are talking about meaning 6a.

Comment: yes! exactly. Do you understand better now?

Comment: @None Yes far better

Comment: Do you want me to write an extended answer or are you happy with what you learnt from the dictionary?

Comment: @None If you don’t mind, I really want an extended answer.

Comment: _He did X for the first time_ means _it was the first occasion on which he had ever done X_.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer to a question of yours that helped you the most. You can accept an answer by clicking on the greyed checkmark, when you do this it turns green and awards the author 15 reputation points. You also get a small reward of two reputation points, it's Stack Exchange's way of saying “Thank you, for contributing”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making up a sentence from your words because context is always important to get a better understanding.

> He drove our new car for the first time when we went to visit our parents.

*Time* here is a countable noun (countable means you can have it in the plural). The sentence means that at some point we acquired a new car and "he" drove it for the first time (for the first instance/occasion) in his life on the day we went to visit our parents.
After that there were several other times/occasions/instances on which he drove the car. And we could talk of a second time, a third time, etc. It's the meaning [you mention in your comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/306333/the-meaning-of-for-the-first-time/306336#comment573209_306333):  [One of several instances](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=time&submit.x=0&submit.y=0).

In your [original question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/306333/2) you referred to the Big Bang and "the beginning of <strike>the</strike> time" (no "the" here). *Time* in that case refers to  "a nonspatial continuum" from past through present to future" ([1.a](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=time&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)). The beginning of time" is a phrase we might find in a religious books, but not only. It means the moment when our World was created. This is not referred to as "the first time, or "a first time", there is just one, it's unique.